# How to seek and append to a binary file in python?

Tags: python, file, seek

I am having problems appending data to a binary file. When i `seek()` to a location, then `write()` at that location and then read the whole file, i find that the data was not written at the location that i wanted. Instead, i find it right after every other data/text.

My code

```
file = open('myfile.dat', 'wb')
file.write('This is a sample')
file.close()

file = open('myfile.dat', 'ab')
file.seek(5)
file.write(' text')
file.close()

file = open('myfile.dat', 'rb')
print file.read()  # -> This is a sample text
```

You can see that the `seek` does not work. How do i resolve this? are there other ways of achieving this?

Thanks

Comment: Note the binary mode isn't important. You can reproduce the same issue with text mode.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

On some systems, `'ab'` forces all writes to happen at the end of the file. You probably want `'r+b'`.

Comment: From the docs for the `seek` method: "If the file is only opened for writing in append mode (mode 'a'), this method is essentially a no-op,"

Comment: @bgporter: Are you supporting or refuting something I said? I honestly can't tell.

Comment: Sorry -- supporting! Just adding the actual text from the docs, trying to clarify (but obviously failing..)

Comment: The non-intuitive part thing is that the docs say `'r+'` opens the file for both reading and *updating* -- with the latter implying being able to write.

Answer (score 6):

r+b should work as you wish

Answer (score 3):

Leave out the seek command. You already opened the file for append with 'a'.

Comment: Judging from the sample code, I don't think the OP wants to append to the end of the file.

Comment: You may be correct but i assumed the result should be 'This is a sample text'. :)

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer. `'r+b'` only works for OP because of the `seek` command.

Answer (score -1):

NOTE : Remember new bytes over write previous bytes

As per python 3 syntax

```
with open('myfile.dat', 'wb') as file:
    b = bytearray(b'This is a sample')
    file.write(b)

with open('myfile.dat', 'rb+') as file:
    file.seek(5)
    b1 = bytearray(b'  text')
    #remember new bytes over write previous bytes
    file.write(b1)

with open('myfile.dat', 'rb') as file:
    print(file.read())
```

OUTPUT

```
b'This   textample'
```

remember new bytes over write previous bytes

Comment: so, how can we wb those two variables into a file and read them?

Comment: Do you mean writing them on different lines? in that case, you can use file.seek(len(b)) the second time. OR best way is to write both variables one after the other when you open file in writing mode. Then close the file. And next time open file in reading mode and read all contents

Comment: it doesn't have to be on a different line, I have posted a question about this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60795901/python-transferring-two-byte-variables-with-a-binary-file. Thanks